# VLOOKUP macro in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I need help on the macro script for the vlookup. I want to hardcode the information of table array in the vlookup script. The problem right now is that when I put the line for the vlookup function it only works on the last line although all the line is actually information from the table of array.

I need help on this to make sure that if the macro run it will start to run the first macro line and go to the second line if nothing match at the first line. Same goes to the third line. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Macro7()

    Range("L1").Select

    Range("L1").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],{1603101,""BFF""},2,FALSE)"
    Range("L1").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],{1603102,""DELTA""},2,FALSE)"
    Range("L1").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],{1608063,""BIST""},2,FALSE)"

    Lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Range("L1").Autofill Destination:=Range("L1:L" & Lastrow)

End Sub
```

Comment: Your macro starts at line 1, then goes to line 2, then line 3 etc. But it keeps overwriting the same cell, so in the end, you only see the third vlookup. Anyway, how do you expect to put 3 different vlookups in one cell? Try stepping through (F8) your code, then you will see it does do everything there.

Comment: yes, it keeps overwriting the same until it find the exact match. my intention right now is want to make sure that each of the cell will run through all list of the vlookup function to find the information which i have total of 1k plus of information that need to be hardcode. With the code above the cell will just directly run the last 3 and give me NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro7()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("L1:L" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],{1603101,""BFF"";1603102,""DELTA"";1608063,""BIST""},2,FALSE)"
    End With
End Sub
```

---

If you were willing to have the VBA code do the calculation itself rather than creating a formula, you could use something like the following code.  (The advantage of doing it via a formula is that it is updated every time the data changes, without needing to invoke the macro again.)

```
Sub Macro7()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim v as String
    With ActiveSheet
        For r = 1 to Range("K" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Select Case .Cells(r, "K").Value
                Case 1603101: v = "BFF"
                Case 1603102: v = "DELTA"
                Case 1608063: v = "BIST"
                Case Else:    v = "UNKNOWN!!"
            End Select
            .Cells(r, "L").Value = v
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. i tried this before and it worked. the problem is right now i have like 1k plus information that i want to hardcode in the vlookup and excel macro does not allow me to do tht. so, instead im trying to make list of vlookup with different information in it. with intention of every column will go through all the list of vlookup function first before move to the next cell. any idea to do this?

Comment: @mhalwi - Why not just set all your VLookup keys/values in a range in Excel and use VLookup normally?

Comment: i want to hardcore it because everytime im pulling the data i dont have to open another excel sheet for the table of array. the problem right now is although the value has been found in second line but when it go through the third line, the value will be replaced as in the third line is not the value that is been searched.

Comment: any way that i can do, after it has found value and it just stop and continue with next cell?

Comment: @mhalwi - Does it **have** to be done by inserting a formula?  Could you just code the tests within VBA code and write the answer to the cell?  (Probably using a `Case Select` statement.)

Comment: thanks for the code above @YowE3k. ill stick to this as for the moments. thanks!!!